# Managing dependent variables in linear model

Tags: linear-model, dependent-variable

I currently have the following problem. I have some data following a linear model
$$y=\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_0$$
(let's say with some Gaussian error) which I would like to estimate. However, I know that there is some additional dependency between the variables involved. Namely, I know that $x_1,x_2,y\geq0$ and that $x_2\leq y$. Additionally, in the data I have available we tend to have $x_2\approx y$, while in the application data we should have $x_2\approx0$, so I really need to disentangle the correlations.

Is there any good approach to this?

---

Luckily enough, while $x_1$ is continuous, in practice it takes discrete values and I happen to have some observations that share $x_1$ (actually more, they are measured from the same event happening). One possibility would be to take these observations for some given value of $x_1$, order them say by $x_{2,1}\leq x_{2,2}\leq\cdots\leq x_{2,k}$ and model
$$y-y_1 = \beta_2(x_2 - x_{2,1}),$$
and then use the estimated $\beta_2$ in the original model.

Does this make sense? What can be the drawbacks (mathematically, what happens to errors etc)? Any reference to relevant literature is very appreciated!